# simple calculator using the freescale tower board

Tags: c

Im trying to finish a homework assigment for class. 
these are the requirements 4    REQUIREMENTS
1.  You name is displayed on the first line of the LCD and it will remain there.
2.  When a numeral key is pressed, the digit of the key will append to the existing digits on line 2 of the LCD.  If line 2 is blank, the digit will appear on the first position of the line.
3.  When ‘#’ key is pressed, the value that is twice the number on line 2 will display on line 3.
4.  Your program must be able to handle the integers between 0 and 2,147,483,647 (inclusive) correctly.  Error conditions when input or result is beyond the range need not be handled.
5.  When ‘*’ key is pressed, the line 2 and line 3 of the LCD are cleared but your name in line 1 shall remain.  You may clear the whole display and repaint the first line.
6.  After ‘*’ key is pressed, the program shall be ready to accept new inputs regardless of whether an error occurred

Im stuck in the part where im supposed to read from my read array and multiply that number by two and display it on the third line.

```
  #include <hidef.h>      /* common defines and macros */
  #include "derivative.h"      /* derivative-specific definitions */
 #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h> 
 #include "keypad.h"
 #include "LCD.h"
 #include "Delays.h"
void main(void)
{

char key;
const unsigned char message[] = "Christian ";   //data in Program Flash
char read [20];
int i=0;
DDRT = 0xF0;     // Upper nibble LEDs: output - logic low turns LED on
initKeypad();


  lcd_init();       // initialize LCD module
  lcd_puts(message); 

for(;;)            // Infinite while loop
{
    key = getKey();
    if(key){
    lcd_putc(key);

    read[i++] = key;
    switch(key){
      case '0':
      case '1':
      case '2':
      case '3':
      case '4':
      case '5':
      case '6':
      case '7':
      case '8':
      case '9':
        break;
      case'#':
        break;
      case'*':
        break;

        default:break;
      atol(read[0]);
      sscanf( ,"%id", );
      read[20] * 2;
      string ltoa(read[0]);
      sprintf( ,"%d", );
      lcd_pos(3,1);           
      lcd_putc(read[20]);

    }
        delayby1ms(10);
        while(getKey());
        delayby1ms(10); 

           }
}//passes message address
}
// end of main function
```

Comment: Does it even compile without any warnings (switch them all on!). Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Is this a partially written program you have to fill in?

Comment: no @Jim, this is my program. The rest of my code is in the other #includes above my main code. The other programs work so theirs no need to look their. My main problem will be here in my main code. I need help reading from the array called "read", getting the data, coverted to long int, multiply it by two and then converted back to string so I could display it back on my LCD.

Comment: Yes it compiles @ED Heal. I know how to use a debugger! Thats not the issue here. I need help with the algorithm.

Comment: It does not even compile. Why not fix that first. Then use a debugger - a useful tool to learn about if you later become a programmer.

Comment: @user2223094 - Not it does not compile - taking a line at random `sprintf( ,"%d", );` is incorrect - see http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf

Comment: Yes it did compile, but after I added this:
          atol(read[0]);
           sscanf( ,"%id", );
           read[20] * 2;
           string ltoa(read[0]);
           sprintf( ,"%d", );
           lcd_pos(3,1);           
           lcd_putc(read[20]);
thats when I started having issues.

Comment: If read is an array of numeric characters, you can get the value with atoi().  With that integer, you can append the new digit (or just add it to the string).  You need to put some of your code (or flags) in the switch statement, so it behaves as it should when certain types of keys are hit.

Comment: So how would I solve this problem? Im trying to multiply the array by two.

Comment: You need to convert the string to an integer  scanf(&val,"%d",read);  Try getting each piece at a time working, comment out the other stuff until the part you are working on works.

Comment: can you post that and include it with my code please? @Jim

Comment: Do you know how to write and read the different lines of the LCD?  That's not clear from your code.  (I tried to do some updates, but they need to be reviewed.)

Answer (score 3):

When the program enters a `switch` statement, it will try to match the controlling expression with each `case` and execute the code after `case` if it matches, execute the code after `default` if none matches. If it reaches a `break`, the program will exit the whole `switch` statement.

In your code, every `case` and `default` is followed by `break`, so the code at the end of `switch` will never be executed.

Your code is a little messy, maybe this is clearer: in this example, the two `printf` will never be executed no matter what value `key` holds.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    char key = 'c';// key can be any character
    switch(key)
    {
        printf("something\n"); // will never execute
        case 'a':
            break;
        case 'b':
            break;
        default:
            break;
        printf("something\n"); // will never execute
    }
    return 0;
}
```